# Java Wait and Notify: IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I don't completely understand how `wait` and `notify` (of `Object`) work, and as a result I'm forced to slim down my attempts into the following section of code.

Main.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main
{
  public static Main main = null;

  public static int numRunners = 4;
  public static ArrayList<Runner> runners = null;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    main = new Main();
  }

  Main()
  {
    runners = new ArrayList<Runner>(numRunners);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRunners; i++)
    {
      Runner r = new Runner();
      runners.add(r);
      new Thread(r).start();
    }

    System.out.println("Runners ready.");
    notifyAll();
  }
}
```

Runner.java:

```
class Runner implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      Main.main.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Runner away!");
  }
}
```

Currently I get an IllegalMonitorStateException when calling `Main.main.wait();`, but I don't understand why.  From what I can see, I need to synchronize `Runner.run`, but in doing so I assume it would only notify one thread, when the idea is to notify them all.

I've looked at `java.util.concurrent`, but I can't find a suitable replacement (maybe I'm just missing something).

Comment: You should never use wait and notify.  They were necessary with the old Java, but now they should only be used by people who write libraries.  You should now use the facilities in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: Agree with toto2, even after you add synchronization this code will not work.  What happens if main calls notifyAll before all the other threads reach wait()?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can't `wait()` on an object unless the current thread owns that object's monitor. To do that, you must `synchronize` on it:

```
class Runner implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      synchronized(Main.main) {
        Main.main.wait();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Runner away!");
  }
}
```

The same rule applies to `notify()`/`notifyAll()` as well.

The [Javadocs for `wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) mention this:

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. See the `notify` method for a description of the ways in which a thread can become the owner of a monitor.
>
> Throws:
>
> [`IllegalMonitorStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) – if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

And from [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29):

> A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three
>   ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - By executing the body of a `synchronized` statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type `Class`, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.

Comment: wait() would release object monitor before blocking its thread, so it would not block other threads calling notify.

Comment: For people linked here, the object you call `wait()` on must be the same object you're synchronizing on. Calling `x.wait()` in a `synchronized(y)` block will yield the same exception.

Answer (score 12):

You're calling both `wait` and `notifyAll` without using a `synchronized` block. In both cases the calling thread *must* own the lock on the monitor you call the method on.

From the docs for `notify` (`wait` and `notifyAll` have similar documentation but refer to `notify` for the fullest description):

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.
>
> Only one thread at a time can own an object's monitor.

Only one thread will be able to actually *exit* `wait` at a time after `notifyAll` as they'll all have to acquire the same monitor again - but all will have been notified, so as soon as the first one then exits the synchronized block, the next will acquire the lock etc.