# java threading, what's wrong with my code

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to update a Object in another thread, and then access it in current thread:

```
 public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.getRealm().exec(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public  void run() {

                    System.out.println("Object at " + rowIndex  + " in WritableList is "  + data.get(rowIndex));
                    object = (DOModel) data.get(rowIndex);
                    System.out.println(object);
                    object.notify();
                }
            });
// suspend current thread
            try {
                synchronized (object){
                    object.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(columnIndex == 0){
                System.out.println(object);
                return object.getId();
            }
    }
```

but when I run my code a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException occurs.

I changed my code, see comments in code:
**Edit --------------------------------**

```
    public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.getRealm().exec(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public  void run() {
                    System.out.println("Object at " + rowIndex  + " in WritableList is "  + data.get(rowIndex));
                    object = (DOModel) data.get(rowIndex);
                    synchronized(object){
                        object.notify();
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                synchronized (object){
                    object.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
// this line below is never executed.
                System.out.println(object);
            if(columnIndex == 0){

                return object.getId();
            }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Wait and Notify: IllegalMonitorStateException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to notify, you need to be synchronized on the monitor. Instead of the unsynchronized notify() in run(), you will need to do:

```
synchronized (object) {
    object.notify();
}
```

You are going to run into race-conditions any way. Your main thread could be trying to synchronize on `object` when it hasn't been retrieved yet in the separate thread.

Better would be to define a separate lock/monitor and use that for synchronisation and notification.

Also, if the separate thread retrieves the object and notifies before your main thread waits, it could be waiting indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

`notify()` call should be within the synchronized block of same monitor