# Java - trying to pause a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Wait and Notify: IllegalMonitorStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception)

What is the problem with

```
    private final Object lock; 
public synchronized void run() {
    while (numItersCompleted < maxNumIters) {
        while (guiState == GuiState.PAUSED) {
            try {
                lock.wait(); // problematic line
```

Throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  You can't `wait()` or `notify()` on an object unless you are in a `synchronized(lock)` block on it.

Comment: You synchronised on `this`, but you waited on `lock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't `synchronized` around the lock.

```
public void run() {
    while (numItersCompleted < maxNumIters) {
        while (guiState == GuiState.PAUSED) {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.wait(); // problematic line
                }
```

I was going to add a link, but Gary bet me to it