# IllegalMonitorStateException notify() and wait()

Tags: java, wait, notify, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I have a problem. When I use `notify()` in a synchronized block I get IllegalMonitorStateException. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I need one thread to send a char to a second thread, then this thread has to wait and second thread print this char. After that second thread wait, and first one again sends next char

Main.java:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
public class Main extends JFrame {

    Thread t1, t2;
    Consumer con;

    public Main() {
        con = new Consumer();
        startThreads();
    }

    private synchronized void startThreads() {
        t1 = new Thread(new Producent("grudzien", con));
        t1.start();
        t2 = new Thread(con);
        t2.start();
    }

    public class Producent implements Runnable {

        String m_atom;
        char[] atoms;
        Consumer m_c;

        public Producent(String atom, Consumer c) {
            m_atom = atom;
            m_c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                atoms = m_atom.toCharArray();
                System.out.print("Tablica znaków: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < atoms.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(atoms[i] + ", ");
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < atoms.length; i++) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    con.setChar(atoms[i]);
                    t2.notify();
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blad w wait()", "Blad!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class Consumer implements Runnable {

        char atom;

        public void setChar(char c) {
            atom = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blad w wait()", "Blad!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    System.out.println(atom);
                    t1.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you include the actual exception please?

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
 at Main$Producent.run(Main.java:53)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/886722/413032

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to be the "owner of the object's monitor" to be able to call notify on it. so far your methods are all `synchronized(this)`, yet they call notify() on other objects (that they are not synchronized on). in other words:

```
synchronized(t2) {
   t2.notify();
}
```

and

```
synchronized(t1) {
   t1.notify();
}
```

for a complete explanation of monitors and synchronization in java, see [here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html), or look for similar questions here on SO, like this one - [Java Wait and Notify: IllegalMonitorStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception)