# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using ProgressDialog. I need to stop the thread when a user closes the ProgressDialog. Unfortunately, it is giving an exception.

In inner class:

```
class UpdateThread extends Thread{

    public  void run() {
        while (true){
            count=adapter.getCount();

            try {
               mHandler.post(  new Runnable() {
                    public  void run() {
                        Log.i(TAG,count+"count");
                        progressDialog.setMessage(count + "Device  found");
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oncreate:

```
 updateThread=new UpdateThread();

 progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(GroupListActivity.this);
 synchronized (this) {
     updateThread.start();
 }
```

Ondismissal:

```
   progressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    updateThread.wait(300);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Thread is stopped");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the locks?

Comment: @Chris its giving exception.so i have to lock

Comment: I understand that you have to use synchronized if you're calling `wait`, but I don't get (a) why you're also synchronizing on calling `updateThread.start`, or (b) why you're using `wait` to begin with (since you're not using `notify` or `notifyAll`). I suspect you're synchronizing and using `wait` where you shouldn't be.

Comment: Added an answer that changes your code to accomplish what it looks like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
synchronized(foo) {
    foo.wait();
}
```

The problem is, what's going to wake this thread up?  That is to say, how do you *guarantee* that the other thread won't call `foo.notify()` *before* the first thread calls `foo.wait()`?  That's important because the foo object will not remember that it was notified if the notify call happens first.  If there's only one notify(), and if it happens before the wait(), then the wait() will never return.

Here's how wait and notify were meant to be used:

```
private Queue<Product> q = ...;
private Object lock = new Object();

void produceSomething(...) {
    Product p = reallyProduceSomething();
    synchronized(lock) {
        q.add(p);
        lock.notify();
    }
}

void consumeSomething(...) {
    Product p = null;
    synchronized(lock) {
        while (q.peek() == null) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        p = q.remove();
    }
    reallyConsume(p);
}
```

The most important things to to note in this example are that there is an explicit test for the condition (i.e., q.peek() != null), and that nobody changes the condition without locking the lock.

If the consumer is called first, then it will find the queue empty, and it will wait.  There is no moment when the producer can slip in, add a Product to the queue, and then notify the lock until the consumer is ready to receive that notification.

On the other hand, if the producer is called first, then the consumer is guaranteed not to call wait().

The loop in the consumer is important for two reasons:  One is that, if there is more than one consumer thread, then it is possible for one consumer to receive a notification, but then another consumer sneaks in and steals the Product from the queue.  The only reasonable thing for the fist consumer to do in that case is wait again for the next Product.  The other reason that the loop is important is that the Javadoc says Object.wait() is allowed to return even when the object has not been notified.  That is called a "spurious wakeup", and the correct way to handle it is to go back and wait again.

Also note:  The lock is `private` and the queue is `private`.  That guarantees that no other compilation unit is going to interfere with the synchronization in this compilation unit.

And note: The lock is a different object from the queue itself.  That guarantees that synchronization in this compilation unit will not interfere with whatever synchronization that the Queue implementation does (if any).

---

NOTE: My example re-invents a wheel to prove a point.  In real code, you would use the put() and take() methods of an ArrayBlockingQueue which would take care of all of the waiting and notifying for you.

Comment: .Awesome explanation.i will try to integreate and let u know

Comment: wait() would release object monitor before blocking its thread, so it would not block other threads calling notify. (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception#comment43938703_7126587)

Comment: @Mygod, Yes.  A call to `o.wait()` releases the calling thread's lock on `o`, then it waits for a notification, and then it re-acquires the lock before it returns.

Comment: @jameslarge I didn't know that so I thought this code wouldn't work.

Comment: I would add "final" modifier to private Object lock

Answer (score 11):

You can only wait on an object if you already hold the lock on it, you could try:

```
synchronized (updateThread) {
    updateThread.wait(300);
}
```

... but I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with the locks.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you're trying to use `synchronized` and `wait` where you shouldn't be.

If you really want to wait for the thread to finish, you should be doing something like this

In your `UpdateThread`:

```
class UpdateThread extends Thread{
    public AtomicBoolean stopped = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public  void run() {
        while (!stopped.get()){
    .....
```

In your creation:

```
updateThread = new UpdateThread();
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupListActivity.this);
updateThread.start();    // no synchronization necessary
```

In your on dismiss:

```
progressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            try {
                updateThread.stopped.set(true);
                updateThread.join(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Thread is stopped");
        }
    });
```

Note, I added an exit condition to your thread so it will actually stop (as is, your thread will keep going). You'd probably want to make the exit condition private and add a setter for cleanliness. Also, I'm using [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) to properly wait for your thread to complete.