# Object not locked by thread before wait in Android app

Tags: android

In my Android app I am trying to execute a task every 5 seconds.

I tried doing something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   //standard initialization code

    letsChange();           //method name

    try{
        wait(1000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printstackstrace();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error message:

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

What do I do to stop this?

Comment: If possible upload your entire code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590542/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-object-not-locked-by-thread-before-wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `wait()` inside a class, you are actually calling `wait()` on the current instance of that class. To do that, it requires a lock on that instance. If another thread has the lock, you will not be able to wait.

Adding `synchronized` to `onCreate()` will acquire the lock (the current instance of the `Activity`) and  let you call `wait()` inside, but this is *definitely* not want you want to do as it will block the main/UI thread and cause your app to be non-responsive.

What you probably want instead is the following inside your activity:

```
private boolean isTerminationConditionMet = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //standard Android onCreate code 

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //code you want to run every second
            if (!isTerminationConditionMet()) {
                handler.postDelayed(task, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
    handler.postDelayed(task, 1000);
}
```

This will cause the code inside `run()` to be run after the desired delay (1000ms) and then every 1000 ms until your termination condition is met.

Comment: But this thing ll run this code after specific time just for once. I want it to run my code every 5 seconds till i say stop. So can i use for loop for this?

Comment: Well then you can add logic to the `Runnable` to loop. Something like `if (!conditionMet()) handler.postDelayed(....)`. You will, of course have to make the `Handler` final to access it from within the `Runnable`