# (probably) Quite simple Java multi-threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime-error

I'm making a platformer in which I make the player jump by, every 30ms, adding a small amount of force upwards. I thought I'd use multi-threading, as I've done a little bit of it before and it seemed simple enough. Anyway, I tried this:

```
public void jump() {
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= jumpForce; i++) {
                velocity.y++;
                System.out.println("Adding force");
                try {
                    wait(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Now, what I *thought* this would do is every loop from 0 to jumpForce (in this case 50), it adds 1 onto the y velocity variable then waits 30ms, but what actually happens is I get an error called:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

and I have no idea what this means so can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to `implement Runnable` in the class deceleration. Did you do that?

Comment: on which class? The Runnable or the class which contains `jump()`?

Comment: Calling `Runnable#run()` alone isn't enough to create a new thread. You need to create a `Thread` from your runnable, then `start()` it.

Comment: Why not a `ScheduledExecutorService`? And you are not actually "multithreading", since the thread is the same that started the runnable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Wait and Notify: IllegalMonitorStateException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute this code in a different thread, than you should **NOT** invoke the `run()` method of the Runnable. What you should do is create an instance of a thread and put your Runnable implementation in its constructor. 
Then invoke `.start()`.

```
 public void jump() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= jumpForce; i++) {
                    velocity.y++;
                    System.out.println("Adding force");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Also you should `sleep()` the thread in this case rather than `wait()`, because you have not taken the object lock. In order to implement what you need using wait(), the method `jump()` must be `synchronized` and another thread must invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc says for `wait` :

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor. See the notify method for a description of the
>   ways in which a thread can become the owner of a monitor.

you own a monitor with a synchronized block, change your code to :

```
synchronized (this) {
  wait(30);
}
```

Comment: I have answered to the IllegalMonitorStateException - your question. but see the other answer : your code is not multithreaded, creating a Runnable is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You are not multithreading, because you are not creating any threads.
The Runnable is running in the same thread that is going to run it. If you want to create a new Thread you have to explicitly do so with `new Thread(new Runnable())` and use `Thread#start()`.

Anyway, you probably just want to schedule a task so better to use a ScheduledExecutorService:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: It's used to run the Runnable every 30s. So you don't have to wait and loop. It will just run again the Runnable.