# suspending, resuming and stopping threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, synchronized-block

I'm learning Thread in java.

The following example shows how to suspend, resume and stop threads:

```
class MyNewThread implements Runnable {
Thread thrd;

boolean suspended;
boolean stopped;

MyNewThread(String name) {
    thrd = new Thread(this, name);
    suspended = false;
    stopped = false;
    thrd.start();
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " starting.");
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            if(i%10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                while(suspended) {
                    wait();
                }
                if(stopped) break;
            }
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " exiting.");
}

synchronized void mystop() {
    stopped = true;
    suspended = false;
    notify();
}

synchronized void mysuspend() {
    suspended = true;
}

synchronized void myresume() {
    suspended = false;
    notify();
}
}

public class Suspend {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyNewThread ob1 = new MyNewThread("My Thread");     
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ob1.mysuspend();
        System.out.println("Suspending Thread.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ob1.myresume();
        System.out.println("Resuming Thread.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ob1.mysuspend();
        System.out.println("Suspending Thread.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ob1.myresume();
        System.out.println("Resuming Thread.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ob1.mysuspend();
        System.out.println("Stopping Thread.");
        ob1.mystop();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted.");
    }

    try {
        ob1.thrd.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Main Thread exiting.");
}
}
```

But this block:

```
synchronized(this) {
    while(suspended) {
        wait();
    }
    if(stopped) break;
}
```

Why this block must be specified synchronized?

I know "synchronized" uses to control Threads's access to shared resource and how to use this key word, but in the example, there're only 2 threads: Main thread and ob1 thread. And Main thread does not enter that synchronized block or any synchronized method in MyThread class. I just cant figure out the reason.

I tried to remove the "synchronized" key word precedes the block. the program returned an error in thread "My Thread" while the main thread still finished it's execution.

Comment: "there're only 2 threads: Main thread and ob1 thread" Yep, that's multiple threads. "And Main thread does not enter that synchronized block" No, but it's not about entering *that* `synchronized` block, it's about entering *any* `synchronized` block which locks on the same monitor.

Comment: "Main thread does not enter that synchronized block or any synchronized method in MyThread class" read again pls

Comment: What do you think the `synchronized` keyword means on a method?

Comment: I'm learning about Thread, I know once a synchronized method has been called on an object, the object is locked and no synchronized methods on the same object's class can be used by another thread

Comment: That's not what it means exactly. Adding `synchronized` to an instance method is exactly equivalent to wrapping the entire method body in `synchronized (this) { /* body */ }`. So it creates mutual exclusion with all other blocks synchronized on `this`, not just synchronized methods.

Comment: yeah, I see. But I still don't know why that block must be specified `synchronized`. As I see, main thread doesn't access any of those synchronized codes. And when I removed `synchronized` keyword, it return error in thread "My Thread" while running, but main thread still finished it's execution. I also tried to removed 1 or 2 `Thread. sleep(250);` along with `synchronized` to find the connection and it worked somehow without error. Can you tell me why? I've been thinking about it since yesterday.

Comment: You have to call `wait()` in a `synchronized` block because that's what the specification says. You can't release a lock you don't own, and syntactically the only way you can reacquire it is if you already held it per the `synchronized` keyword in the first place.

Comment: oh, shit! It's basic and i had so much thought on it. The while loop must call `wait()` as it's purpose and `wait()` only be used within `synchronized` codes. Thanks EJP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your **direct** question: you need to **synchronize** on `this` because you are calling `wait()` on `this`.

And in order for wait() to be called, the calling thread must own the **monitor** of the object wait() is called on.

So: you need that synchronized block (or method) to prevent an [IllegalMonitorStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception) for the following call to wait()!

Comment: Right, tks! I forgot it's a requirement to call `wait()`.