# Incharge Thread make other Threads to wait

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I've 2 Thread that work `synchronized` to withdraw money from the `Bank`.

I've created an `Incharge` Thread that should run every 30Seconds and its should take 15Seconds long.

During the 15 Seconds, Thread1 and Thread2 that withdraw the money should wait until `Incharge` Thread finish.

Which mean, T1 and T2 should have 15Seconds to withdraw the money until Incharge return from sleep until the balance is zero

I am trying to do it with `t1.wait(15*SECOND)` but I receive:

> Exception in thread "inCharge" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
> at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)   at
> InCharge.run(InCharge.java:15)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

My feeling is that I'm not doing it correct.

Main:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int startingBalance = 100000;
        Bank bank = new Bank(startingBalance);
        Thread client1 = new ClientThread(bank, 1);
        Thread client2 = new ClientThread(bank, 2);
        Thread inCharge = new Thread(new InCharge(bank, client1, client2));
        client1.setName("T1");
        client2.setName("T2");
        inCharge.setName("inCharge");


        inCharge.start();
        client1.start();
        client2.start();
    }
}
```

InCharge :

```
public class InCharge extends Thread {
    public static final int SECOND = 1000;
    private Bank bank;
    private Thread t1,t2;
    InCharge(Bank bank, Thread t1, Thread t2){
        this.bank = bank;
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Charge is here!, current balance is: " + bank.getBalance());
                this.t1.wait(15*SECOND);
                this.t2.wait(15*SECOND);
                Thread.sleep(30 * SECOND);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bank:

```
public class Bank {
    private int balance;
    public Bank(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public synchronized void withdraw(String name, int amount){
        if (this.balance - amount >= 0) {
            this.balance = this.balance - amount;
            System.out.println(name+" "+this.balance + " withdrawed - " + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

ClientThread:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private Bank bank;
    private int client;

    ClientThread(Bank bank, int client) {
        this.bank = bank;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int randomNumber;
        while (bank.getBalance() > 0) {
            randomNumber = ((int) (Math.random() * (5000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000);
            try {
                bank.withdraw(Thread.currentThread().getName(),randomNumber);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this answer helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7126587/10416835

Comment: This exception means that you've done a `wait` or `notify` on an object while not having it locked. Put the specific code in a `synchronized`-block with the object as lock.

Comment: @akuzminykh how could I tell wait to 2 Threads, using `synchronized`?

Comment: @itzikb Not sure what you mean, you can just tell both threads to wait. It's not limited.

Comment: I've manage to tell them to wait when the `Incharge` is in action, but how do i make them wait only 15Seconds while Incharge should take 30seconds